# Serial Converter in Java

Tags: java, serial-port, communication, rs485, industrial

I'm searching for an industrial serial to USB converter.
I want to use it within my JAVA application to communicate with various devices.
Therefore the serial adapter has to provide a mode for RS232, RS422 and RS485.
Furthermore there should be a library which enables me to enable and disable the buffer in the serial adapter.

I tried the MOXA Uport 1150, which does a great job. The problem with this adapter is, that the serial mode (232,422,485) can't be changed within a Java-application and the buffer of the MOXA can't be enabled/disabled either.

I hope someone can help me!

Michael

Comment: Which `Java` library are you using for communicating via serial ports?

Comment: I use a Moxa NPort device.  I haven't tried changing the 232/422/485 setting programmatically, but you can certainly change it in the web interface.  I use another Moxa product in which I toggle settings via CGI commands using libcurl, so it may be possible to change the 232/422/485 settings this way, provided you knew the correct commands (Moxa tech support is good about providing this info).  As for custom buffer size, I couldn't find anything there, but maybe the "Data Packing" functionality might help to give you data in a specific size you need?  Why would you disable the buffer?

Comment: Have you considered an Ethernet to serial converter implementing RFC2217? While slightly more expensive,  they are much better to work with in Java.